# Why won't this div just center?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I have been trying to center the very bottom row of blue cards. As you can see it is not:

[image]

So far I have tried `text-align`, `width: 100%;`, and `margin-left: auto; margin right: auto;`

But it will just not center! Is there something I am obviously executing poorly/wrong?

HTML:

```
<!-------------------     SKILLS     --------------------->

        <section>
            <div class="container-fluid skillset">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h3>Skills</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>


            <div class="row lang">

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card card-outline-primary text-xs-center">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
                                <p><i class="fa fa-html5" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card card-outline-primary text-xs-center">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
                                <p><i class="fa fa-css3" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card card-outline-primary text-xs-center">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
                                <p><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card card-outline-primary text-xs-center">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
                                <p><i class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

</div>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
/* -------------------------------------
SKILLS
--------------------------------------*/

.card {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 5px; /* 5px rounded corners */
   /* margin-left: 30%; */
}

/* Add rounded corners to the top left and the top right corner of the image */
img {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */
.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.lang {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @Martin I did this, and it did not work :(

Comment: fair enough, I read that you'd already tried to use it but you hadn't  stated in which element(s) you'd used it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make `.card` an inline-block (`display: inline-block`) and use `text-align: center` on its parent/s. You might want to give those parent `col-md-3` elements a dedicated class for this purpose.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you, I have been struggling with this for a while. I will accept you as a answer as soon as my 5 minute timer is over.

Answer (score 4):

Add `display: inline-block;` to `.col-md-3`.
https://jsfiddle.net/q6hpqob1/

```css
.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 5px;  /* 5px rounded corners */
  /* margin-left: 30%; */
}


/* Add rounded corners to the top left and the top right corner of the image */

img {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.lang {
  text-align: center;
}

.col-md-3 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
display: inline-block; /*add this*/
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid skillset">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h3>Acomplishments</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <h4>Internship</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <p>Every day is taco ipsum tuesday. Tacos Al pastor/De Adobada are made of thin pork steaks seasoned with adobo seasoning, then skewered and overlapped on one another on a vertical rotisserie cooked and flame-broiled as it spins. 50 cent tacos! I’ll
          take 30. Carne asada on corn tortillas. Let’s do a beef and a chicken, and one with both. I’ve been following that taco truck around all day. Josh’s taco shack is the best taco shack. Let’s do a beef and a chicken, and one with both. CARNE ASADA!!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h4>Live Project</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>Every day is taco ipsum tuesday. Tacos Al pastor/De Adobada are made of thin pork steaks seasoned with adobo seasoning, then skewered and overlapped on one another on a vertical rotisserie cooked and flame-broiled as it spins. 50 cent tacos! I’ll
          take 30. Carne asada on corn tortillas. Let’s do a beef and a chicken, and one with both. I’ve been following that taco truck around all day. Josh’s taco shack is the best taco shack. Let’s do a beef and a chicken, and one with both. CARNE ASADA!!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h3>Skills</h3>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row lang">

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card card-outline-primary text-xs-center">
          <div class="card-block">
            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
              <p><i class="fa fa-html5" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card card-outline-primary text-xs-center">
          <div class="card-block">
            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
              <p><i class="fa fa-css3" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card card-outline-primary text-xs-center">
          <div class="card-block">
            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
              <p><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card card-outline-primary text-xs-center">
          <div class="card-block">
            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
              <p><i class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

I've added height,width,and border, to them, because they are essentially empty.
But you can just remove that when you put the icons in it.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this class to the `<div class='row lang'>` div:

```
.flex {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* or center */
  flex-wrap:nowrap
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```css
.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* 5px rounded corners */
  /* margin-left: 30%; */
}
/* Add rounded corners to the top left and the top right corner of the image */

img {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.lang {
  text-align: center;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;/* or center */
  flex-wrap: nowrap
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<section>
  <div class="container-fluid skillset">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h3>Acomplishments</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <h4>Internship</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <p>Every day is taco ipsum tuesday. Tacos Al pastor/De Adobada are made of thin pork steaks seasoned with adobo seasoning, then skewered and overlapped on one another on a vertical rotisserie cooked and flame-broiled as it spins. 50 cent tacos! I’ll
          take 30. Carne asada on corn tortillas. Let’s do a beef and a chicken, and one with both. I’ve been following that taco truck around all day. Josh’s taco shack is the best taco shack. Let’s do a beef and a chicken, and one with both. CARNE ASADA!!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h4>Live Project</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>Every day is taco ipsum tuesday. Tacos Al pastor/De Adobada are made of thin pork steaks seasoned with adobo seasoning, then skewered and overlapped on one another on a vertical rotisserie cooked and flame-broiled as it spins. 50 cent tacos! I’ll
          take 30. Carne asada on corn tortillas. Let’s do a beef and a chicken, and one with both. I’ve been following that taco truck around all day. Josh’s taco shack is the best taco shack. Let’s do a beef and a chicken, and one with both. CARNE ASADA!!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h3>Skills</h3>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row lang flex">

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card card-outline-primary text-xs-center">
          <div class="card-block">
            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
              <p><i class="fa fa-html5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </p>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card card-outline-primary text-xs-center">
          <div class="card-block">
            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
              <p><i class="fa fa-css3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </p>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card card-outline-primary text-xs-center">
          <div class="card-block">
            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
              <p><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </p>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card card-outline-primary text-xs-center">
          <div class="card-block">
            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
              <p><i class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </p>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

for bootstrap3 the class for center  is text-center

```
              <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                <div class="card card-outline-primary text-xs-center">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
                            <p><i class="fa fa-html5" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using `margin: 0 auto;` css on inner divs you can do it easily.

```css
.inblock{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

```html
<div>

  <center>
    <div class="inblock">1</div>
    <div class="inblock">2</div>
    <div class="inblock">3</div>
    <div class="inblock">4</div>
  </center>
  
</div>
```